# Remove all environment variable and load rcfile

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I need to run multiple sets of environments. For this, I have two sets of bashrc files, `bashrc_a` and `bashrc_b`. On startup, I made `bashrc_a` running by making `.bashrc` as

```
source bashrc_a
```

From `bashrc_a` environment, I need to switch to `bashrc_b`, but I don't want to involve any environment variables from `bashrc_a` remain in the `bashrc_b` environment. For this, I tried

```
env -i bash --rcfile bashrc_b
```

But the problem is, in this case, I lose **all** environment variables, not just those from `bashrc_a`. I have no `HOME`, I have no `PATH`, and so on.

Another thing I tried is

```
env -i bash --login --rcfile bashrc_b
```

But if I do this, login shell looks up for `~/.bashrc`, then it looks up for `bashrc_a` file, and also, since `TERM` is deleted from `env -i`, it did not help.

So my question is, how do I *unload* `bashrc_a` and load `bashrc_b`?

Comment: Use `environment-modules`, it is designed for such tasks. You may need a bit more time to configure it first, but it is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound, from what you describe, like you don't *actually* want to load the `bashrc_b` environment from `bashrc_a`.

Assuming that you *dont't* source either of `bashrc_a` or `bashrc_b` from `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

1. Start a `bash` shell as normal.
2. Start the `bashrc_a` environment with `bash --rcfile bashrc_a`.
3. If you want to switch to the `bashrc_b` environment

   1. first `exit`, and then
   2. `bash --rcfile bashrc_b`

If you want to *keep* the `bashrc_a` environment around, then just open another terminal and do `bash --rcfile bashrc_b`.

The other alternative would be to write a corresponding "unload" `rc`-file for each of the environments.  These two files would unset or re-set the environment in such a way that they un-did whatever the corresponding `bashrc_x` file did.  You may then `source bashrc_a`, do your work, `source unbashrc_a`, followed by `source bashrc_b` (or have `bashrc_b` source `unbashrc_a` directly).

This may be tricky to write and to keep up to date though.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but I kinda figured a way with your answer. It turns out, to make `bash` forget all environment arguments, just `bash --login` is enough. So I -_similar to your answer_- removed `bashrc_a` from default `.bashrc` and made a couple of scripts to switch between two environments without a big effort.